# Error in setOnItemSelectedListener in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

am getting an error in my GridView, am displaying a grid view from strings. I want to show an alert dialog when i select any row of the grid view. But My problem is when am scrolling the grid view it is showing the Alert Dialog. Here is my code.

```
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(/*Adapter class*/);

    grid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,   int pos, long id) {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ApprovePunches.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Approve...");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
            alertDialog.setButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 alertDialog.dismiss();
               }
            });
            alertDialog.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     alertDialog.dismiss();
                   }
                });

            alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame);
            alertDialog.show();

        }



        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }
    });
```

Can anyone please help me in doing this. Thank you.

Comment: @Deva: i dont no how to express, error in the sense not forcibly closing or giving error messages in logcat, when i click on item it is nothing doing, but when try to scroll it is showing the alert....

Comment: I think follow Binyamins instruction below. should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to show a Alert Dialog in onItemSelected Listener. Your onItemSelectedListener gets called when ever there is a change in your View.(Eg. During Scroll event ).

If you want to display a Dialog based on user action, you can use setOnItemClickListener like this,

grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,   int pos, long id) {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ApprovePunches.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Approve...");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
        alertDialog.setButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             alertDialog.dismiss();
           }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 alertDialog.dismiss();
               }
            });

        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame);
        alertDialog.show();

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` for GridView, not `setOnItemSelectedListener`.